# Check if Bool Value Changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, observers

I want to hide my button in my Popover class, whenever my bool value in the other class is false, but the Problem is i don't get the "TRUE" value.

My First Class

```
 -(void) hideButton{
        finished = _secondVC.finished;
        BOOL isRunning = !finished;
        if(isRunning){
        _deleteButton.hidden = YES;
        }else if(finished){
            _deleteButton.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
```

I call the method of hideButton in my ViewWillAppear function.

My Second Class

```
-(void) someAction{
  if(something){
  self.finished = YES;
}
```

EDIT:

Now, if i load the Popover and the NSNotification gets fired the button is enabled, but the Problem is, if i close and open the popover, my delete button is still disabled.

My PopOver Class

```
  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if(syncFinished){
          _deleteButton.enabled = YES;
    }else if(!syncFinished){
        _deleteButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(showButton)
                                                         name:@"syncFinish"
                                                       object:nil];
     }

    - (void) showButton{
     syncFinished = YES;
      _deleteButton.enabled = YES;
     }
```

My Second Class

```
-(void) someAction{
  if(something){
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"syncFinish"
                                                        object:self];
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where are you observing a `BOOL` value? How are the two methods from these two classes connected?

Comment: You need to be clearer than "don't get the true value". I'm guessing you might be using the word "Observing" in the title in its English sense, while readers are assuming you mean it's technical meaning in "Key value observing" (KVO). Edit your question to provide more detail and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: The logic in your code is torturous. Please understand that `if (thing)` then `else` already means `!thing` and there is no need to put `else if (!thing)`.

Answer (score -1):

you can't directly observe the value.

you could send a `NSNotification` when the action starts/finishes and observe for that in your first class to show/hide the button.

Comment: not saying it's a good idea, but KVO could be used with `finished` on the second VC

Comment: well this one worked for me. But whenever i close my view and reload it again the delete button won't be enabled. Because the method doesn't get fired again.

Comment: yeah ... in that case you have to check the value when you create the button.. the notification will only work if the object is already there

Answer (score -1):

I solved This Problem with the NSUserDefaults. so I can set the bool if someAction is happening. And in every other class i can read the bool.
so in my Second Class:

```
 -(void) someAction{
       if(something){
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"syncFinish"];
        } else {
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"syncFinish"];
        }
```

In My Popover Class i say

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"syncFinish"]) {
            _deleteButton.enabled = NO;
        } else {
            _deleteButton.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Terrible idea.  That is not what `NSUserDefaults` was designed for.

Comment: well I didn't find any other solution that worked for me.